# bluetooth earphone with usb

Tags: bluetooth, usb-device

I have a Sony bluetooth earphone. It has a usb terminal, which I thought it was only for the purpose of charging power. But when I connected it to a computer, it seems like it is detected as a usb device, not just taking power from the computer. What is the purpose of it being designed to be detected as a usb device? I am planning to replace the usb terminal (mini B female) to usb A male so that I can charge power to it without cable. If I only connect V+ and V- and ignore Data+ and Data-, would I lose some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the data connection is for firmware upgrades, since 100mA is usually more than adequate for charging purposes for a Bluetooth earpiece. If you feel confident that the device is secure and working properly then you can go ahead and leave the data lines floating.